# How to display current login user data when it is divided into section in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing my app idea I am struck with a database. I'm using Firebase to my Android app I have to divide the user as sections

```
Root
    |
    |___users
               |
               |___secA
               |         |__UIDS
               |         |        |__NAME
               |         |        |__ROLLNO
               |         |__\\other uids of users
               |           
               | 
               |___secb
               |          |__uids
               |          |       |__name
               |          |       |__ rollno
               |          |__\\other uids of user
               |___upto n sec
```

The current user uid will present in one of the sections(seca,secb,n)and in all uids there  is common user data(name and rollno) now i want know in which section current user uid is present and display the all data of the current user thanks for taking time and answering my quetions

Comment: Did you do a google search or read firebase docs? sec-a sec-b could be fields. you need to search and find some login example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your going to have to loop through the sections to check where it exists.

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FireabaseAuth.getInstance();
String uid = mAuth.getCurrrentUser().getUid();

DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    ref.child("Root").child("Users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) 
        {
            for (DatasnapShot sectionSnap : dataSnapshot.getChildren() )
            {
                if (sectionSnap.child(uid).exists())
                {
                    //User exists in this section.

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Janwilx72 thanx for answering my question  but i want the user data present in uid of a student in which his her uid present in one of the sec               root- users-seca,secb,sec_c.......                                                   in each section i.e( seca,secb,sec_c)  the uids of students present.....and in their respective uids their data will be there..plz help me iam new to firebase

Comment: Please show me a full path in your firebase with example data, and I can provide you with an answer

Comment: i have edited my quetion please check it once thanks for finding time to me